# Extra space on the right of bootstrap container in safari

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have encountered this error in safari 5.1.7. I have a row with 12 columns, the problem is when viewed in safari, the container adds extra space to the right.

Here's the code:

css

```
.wrapper {

    background:blue;
  }

  .wrapper .container {

    background:red;

  }

  .wrapper .container .row .col {

    height:30px;
    background:grey;
    padding: 0;
  }
```

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class='col-xs-1 col'></div>
      <div class='col-xs-1 col'></div>
      <div class='col-xs-1 col'></div>
      <div class='col-xs-1 col'></div>
      <div class='col-xs-1 col'></div>
      <div class='col-xs-1 col'></div>
      <div class='col-xs-1 col'></div>
      <div class='col-xs-1 col'></div>
      <div class='col-xs-1 col'></div>
      <div class='col-xs-1 col'></div>
      <div class='col-xs-1 col'></div>
      <div class='col-xs-1 col'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code works fine on all browser except safari.

Here it is in [chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uW0bh.jpg)

Here it is in [safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeNPw.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not surprising because of the version you are using is so old. Bootstrap does document this issue in the documentation though:

> **Safari percent rounding**
>
> The rendering engine of versions of Safari prior to v7.1 for OS X and
>   Safari for iOS v8.0 had some trouble with the number of decimal places
>   used in our .col-*-1 grid classes. So if you had 12 individual grid
>   columns, you'd notice that they came up short compared to other rows
>   of columns. Besides upgrading Safari/iOS, you have some options for
>   workarounds:
>
> - Add .pull-right to your last grid column to get the hard-right alignment
> - Tweak your percentages manually to get the perfect rounding for Safari (more difficult than the first option)

I wouldnt bother with support for a browser that is no longer in use though.